# Rails ancestry association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I have a recipe app where each recipe is associated with a number of ingredients and the ingredients are organized using the [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem.

```
class Ingredient < AR::Base
  has_ancestry
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class Recipe < AR::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end
```

So, for example, "soy sauce" would be an ingredient and "kikkoman" would be a child of "soy sauce".  A recipe might call for "soy sauce" or specifically call out "kikkoman" by name.

I want to be able to search recipes by ancestry, so if I ran a search for "soy sauce" it would also find recipes with the child "kikkoman".  How can I accomplish this with Rails magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `ingredient_key` is the given ingredient (soy sauce), this could give you all recipes:

`(ingredient_key.ancestors + ingredient_key + ingredient_key.descendants).map(&:recipes).flatten.uniq` .

You could omit ancestors if you only wanted recipes of that ingredient and its children.

Comment: Since I didn't need ancestors, I just used ingredient.subtree which includes both ingredient and its descendants.